# Problem using Boost Logging and ERROR priority 3 to syslog database

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I have a program which make use of boost logging and most of the time this program writes logs either to a local file or when deployed to /var/log/messages via rsyslog. Most of the time we are just interested in seeing Error (boost::log::trivial::error) but when in development we want to log at higher levels.
Everything seeems great with this method of logging, we also have several python scripts that also make use of rsyslog, they also put normally into /va/log/messages without issue.

My recent task as a developer is to move logging from /va/log/messages into postgres database table to allow an external client to get notification of when an error might happen. Anyway I've manages to get my logging into said database with a few tweaks to the /etc/rsyslog.conf file and adding files to our postgres database.

During my debugging process I have noticed with my C++ application every time I write a LOG ERROR to the syslog, the priority (column in database table) is set to level 6(info) and not level 3(error) (from rsyslog web pages). The python code always logs priority leve 3. This make it very difficult to now filter on.
My boost config is as:

```
   if (syslog)
   {
       // Create a backend
       m_syslogSink = boost::make_shared<syslog_sink>(
            boost::log::keywords::facility = boost::log::sinks::syslog::user,
            boost::log::keywords::use_impl = boost::log::sinks::syslog::native
        );

        // Set the straightforward level translator for the "Severity" attribute of type int
        m_syslogSink->locked_backend()->set_severity_mapper(
            boost::log::sinks::syslog::direct_severity_mapping<int>("Severity"));
        
        m_syslogSink->set_formatter(
            boost::log::expressions::stream
                << boost::log::expressions::if_(boost::log::expressions::has_attr(unitName))[
                        boost::log::expressions::stream << '[' << unitName << "] "
                    ]
                << boost::log::expressions::smessage
            );

        // Share the filter level with the file log level but don't allow trace
        m_syslogSink->set_filter(boost::bind(
            &LogFilter, &m_fileLogLevel,
            boost::log::trivial::debug, boost::log::trivial::fatal,
            LogSource::LogType::FILE_OR_SYSLOG, ::_1));

        // Register the syslog sink with the logging core
        core->add_sink(m_syslogSink);
    }
```

our LOG_ERROR breaks down into   BOOST_LOG_SEV(LogControl::getLog()->log, boost::log::trivial::error) << "A Error message";

Anyone know why this might be is it a known bug? in the boost library or have I done something stupid or is it not possible. I am using the boost::log::trivial::error level.

the /etc/rsyslog.conf contains the line
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none             :ompgsql:127.0.0.1,syslog,rsyslog,secret
to place it into the database.

and raising a syslog log error using python code which does what I want
syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERROR, "ERROR message")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The python code always logs priority leve 3" - whoa where did python come from suddenly

Comment: There's very little we can act on. We just have to take your word for what you're doing, and we have no idea how you wired up any configuration. That means that even if we're interested we can't try it out. That makes the question not very useful in its current form.